# Java xml creation with JDOM/XML

Tags: java, xml, web-services, jdom

I have an problem in creating xml with the

```
    <c:condition>
        <a:condition>
            <fieldName>fieldName</fieldName>
            <fieldTest>fieldTest</fieldTest>
            <fieldValues>
                <fieldValue>fieldValue</fieldValue>
            </fieldValues>
        </a:condition>
        <operator>operator</operator>
        <a:condition>
            <fieldName>fieldName</fieldName>
            <fieldTest>fieldTest</fieldTest>
            <fieldValues>
                <fieldValue>fieldValue</fieldValue>
            </fieldValues>
        </a:condition>
    </c:condition>
```

Above is the xml tag given to me.

I need to create this tag using the JDOM/XML in java.

So I am using

```
Element complexCondition = new Element("c:condition");
```

code to create "c:condition" tag.

But I am getting error

```
org.jdom.IllegalNameException: The name "c:condition" is not legal for JDOM/XML elements: Element names cannot contain colons.
```

So don't have any idea what is going wrong.
As I am new to the xml's and JDOM.
Please help me out with this issue.

Comment: See: http://www.jdom.org/docs/faq.html#a0250 about the colon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
c:
```

is a namespace prefix. you should create your element with namespace. check the constructor :

```
Element(java.lang.String name, java.lang.String prefix, java.lang.String uri)
  Creates a new element with the supplied (local) name and a namespace given by the supplied prefix and URI combination.
```